# React syncing column width of between tables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How I can syncing column width of between tables?

I have a two tables (there will be more tr). The column `td` width of the first table should be the same as the second one. Or vice versa.

My code is not working:

```js
import React, { createRef, useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const tableRefs = useRef([]);

  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);

  const list1 = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5'];
  const list2 = ['Lorem Item 1', 'pixel 2', 'set 3', 'amet 4', 'Item 5'];

  tableRefs.current = [...Array(list2.length).keys()].map(
    (_, i) => tableRefs.current[i] ?? createRef()
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const tableRefsItems = tableRefs.current;

    tableRefsItems.forEach((el, i) => {
      const rect = el.current.clientWidth;

      setWidth(rect);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <table>
        <tr>
          {list1.map((item, i) => (
            <td
              className="nav-item"
              key={i}
              style={{
                border: '1px solid',
                width: width + 'px',
              }}
            >
              {item}
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table>
        <tr>
          {list2.map((item, i) => (
            <td
              key={i}
              ref={tableRefs.current[i]}
              style={{
                border: '1px solid',
                width: width + 'px',
              }}
            >
              <h3>{item}</h3>
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
table {
table-layout: fixed;

}
```

```html
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How do you decide which width to take? Which table should 'win'?

Comment: @Titulum, second table td

Answer (score 1):

Please use CSS in such cases. Use grid and flex. CSS is better optimized for your case. If you need value of width of column `td`.

js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState({});
  const ref = useRef();

  const resizeHandler = () => {
    const { clientHeight, clientWidth } = ref.current || {};
    setSize({ clientHeight, clientWidth });
  };

  const list1 = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"];
  const list2 = ["Lorem Item 1", "pixel 2", "set 3", "amet 4", "Item 5"];

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);
    resizeHandler();
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr
            ref={ref}
            style={{
              gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${list1.length}, 1fr)`,
            }}
          >
            {list1.map((item, i) => (
              <td className="nav-item" key={i}>
                {item}
              </td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr
            style={{
              gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${list2.length}, 1fr)`,
            }}
          >
            {list2.map((item, i) => (
              <td key={i}>
                <h3>{item}</h3>
              </td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <div>width table tr:{size.clientWidth}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

CSS:

```
tr {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100vw;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table,
tbody {
    display: block;
}
```

If you don't need width of column `td`:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  const list1 = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5"];
  const list2 = ["Lorem Item 1", "pixel 2", "set 3", "amet 4", "Item 5"];

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr
            style={{
              gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${list1.length}, 1fr)`,
            }}
          >
            {list1.map((item, i) => (
              <td className="nav-item" key={i}>
                {item}
              </td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr
            style={{
              gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${list2.length}, 1fr)`,
            }}
          >
            {list2.map((item, i) => (
              <td key={i}>
                <h3>{item}</h3>
              </td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

CSS:

```
tr {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100vw;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table,
tbody {
    display: block;
}
```